# Is it possible to filter bad language words using Java?

Tags: java

I was wondering if it's possible to filter bad language words. An example of filtering profanity is a username when they create an account so it can inform users that this word is unacceptable.

Is it possible?
Thanks :)

Comment: What does this have to do with Swing? What you are trying to do will involve your program's model, not its GUI, and so the GUI library should not effect the solution.

Comment: Swing doesn't have out-of box feature like that. But it is definitely possible to build your own filter and integrate with your swing app.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521646/whats-the-best-profanity-filter-which-supports-java-integration

Comment: @Steve WOW! I tried to find this but thanks for linking it steve!

Comment: No.  It never works.  It blocks legitimate discussions while allowing all sorts of nasty stuff through.  Doing even a mediocre job requires a major effort with sophisticated syntax analysis, et al.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's not possible to filter bad language words using any programming language.

The best you can do is create a List of bad language words, and check against the List.  You will be adding words to the List for as long as your system exists.

Here's a simple example to illustrate the problem.  Let's assume "hell" is a bad language word.  Here are some of the variations of "hell".

```
h e l l
h e 1 l (one, l)
h e l 1 (l, one)
he1l
hel1
he11
he ll
etc.
```

And that's one word.  Imagine how much fun your users will have coming up with variations to all of the bad language words.

Comment: Not to mention "hello", "breast cancer", real female dogs, and untold other perfectly legitimate phrases that will be blocked.

Answer (score 1):

```
Example with simple java run the Test.java with some input:  
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class BadWordFilter {

  private static int largestWordLength = 0;

  private static Map<String, String[]> allBadWords = new HashMap<String, String[]>();

  /**
   * Iterates over a String input and checks whether any cuss word was found - and for any/all cuss word found, 
   * as long as the cuss word should not be ignored (i.e. check for false positives - e.g. even though "bass" 
   * contains the word *ss, bass should not be censored) then (in the String returned) replace the cuss word with asterisks.
   */
  public static String getCensoredText(final String input) {
      loadBadWords();
    if (input == null) {
      return "";
    }

    String modifiedInput = input;

    // remove leetspeak
    modifiedInput = modifiedInput.replaceAll("1", "i").replaceAll("!", "i").replaceAll("3", "e").replaceAll("4", "a")
        .replaceAll("@", "a").replaceAll("5", "s").replaceAll("7", "t").replaceAll("0", "o").replaceAll("9", "g");

    // ignore any character that is not a letter
    modifiedInput = modifiedInput.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "");

    ArrayList<String> badWordsFound = new ArrayList<>();

    // iterate over each letter in the word
    for (int start = 0; start < modifiedInput.length(); start++) {
      // from each letter, keep going to find bad words until either the end of
      // the sentence is reached, or the max word length is reached.
      for (int offset = 1; offset < (modifiedInput.length() + 1 - start) && offset < largestWordLength; offset++) {
        String wordToCheck = modifiedInput.substring(start, start + offset);
        if (allBadWords.containsKey(wordToCheck)) {
          String[] ignoreCheck = allBadWords.get(wordToCheck);
          boolean ignore = false;
          for (int stringIndex = 0; stringIndex < ignoreCheck.length; stringIndex++) {
            if (modifiedInput.contains(ignoreCheck[stringIndex])) {
              ignore = true;
              break;
            }
          }

          if (!ignore) {
            badWordsFound.add(wordToCheck);
          }
        }
      }
    }

    String inputToReturn = input;
    for (String swearWord : badWordsFound) {
      char[] charsStars = new char[swearWord.length()];
      Arrays.fill(charsStars, '*');
      final String stars = new String(charsStars);

      // The "(?i)" is to make the replacement case insensitive.
      inputToReturn = inputToReturn.replaceAll("(?i)" + swearWord, stars);
    }

    return inputToReturn;
  } // end getCensoredText

  private static void loadBadWords() {
    int readCounter = 0;
    try {
      // The following spreadsheet is from: https://gist.github.com/PimDeWitte/c04cc17bc5fa9d7e3aee6670d4105941
      // (If the spreadsheet ever ceases to exist, then this application will still function normally otherwise - it just won't censor any swear words.)

             FileReader fr = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\sshah\\Downloads\\Word_Filter - Sheet1.csv");
             BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fr);

//      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new URL(
//          "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hIEi2YG3ydav1E06Bzf2mQbGZ12kh2fe4ISgLg_UBuM/export?format=csv")
//          .openConnection().getInputStream()));


      String currentLine = "";
      while ((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        readCounter++;
        String[] content = null;
        try {
          if (1 == readCounter) {
            continue;
          }

          content = currentLine.split(",");
          if (content.length == 0) {
            continue;
          }

          final String word = content[0];

          if (word.startsWith("-----")) {
            continue;
          }

          if (word.length() > largestWordLength) {
            largestWordLength = word.length();
          }

          String[] ignore_in_combination_with_words = new String[] {};
          if (content.length > 1) {
            ignore_in_combination_with_words = content[1].split("_");
          }

          // Make sure there are no capital letters in the spreadsheet
          allBadWords.put(word.replaceAll(" ", "").toLowerCase(), ignore_in_combination_with_words);
        } catch (Exception except) {
        }
      } // end while
    } catch (IOException except) {
    }
  } // end loadBadWords

}
Ref Link : 
https://github.com/souwoxi/Profanity
```

Comment: This has a problem. I write "assay" and it returned to me "***ay". That's what I want to avoid, false positives like this.