# Issues with char array and replacing words

Tags: java, arrays, char

I am attempting to iterate through characters for a "curse word filter", there is a config file that defines what the curse words will be replaced with. Sometimes my code is grabbing the last letter/number of the key and putting it at the end of the key string.

Tried doing this in a few different ways, the whole attempt of this is to avoid case sensitivity and find every possible attempt at beating it.
here's an example of it breaking - http://prntscr.com/nqyirl

```
public void onChat(AsyncPlayerChatEvent event)
    {
        String originalMessage = event.getMessage();
        ArrayList<String> swearWords = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String key : getConfig().getConfigurationSection("replace-words").getKeys(false))
            swearWords.add(key);
        ArrayList<Character> charArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (char c : originalMessage.toCharArray())
            charArrayList.add(c);
        for (String swearWord : swearWords)
        {
            Bukkit.broadcastMessage(swearWord);
            int startIndex;
            if ((startIndex = originalMessage.toLowerCase().indexOf(swearWord)) != -1)
            {
                int endIndex = startIndex + swearWord.length();
                for (int i = startIndex; i < endIndex; i++)
                {
                    charArrayList.remove(startIndex);
                    charArrayList.trimToSize();
                }
                char[] replaceWith = getConfig().getString("replace-words." + swearWord).toCharArray();
                Bukkit.broadcastMessage(new String(replaceWith));
                for (int i = 0; i < replaceWith.length; i++) {
                    char c = replaceWith[i];
                    charArrayList.add(startIndex + i, c);

                }
            }
        }
        final char[] array = new char[charArrayList.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
            array[i] = charArrayList.get(i);
        event.setMessage(new String(array));
    }
```

Config File -

```
#configurables, enjoy
replace-words:
  test1234: testo22345566
```

It should be replacing `test1234 with testo22345566`, instead it adds a 4 on the end. Making it - testo223455664. Example here - http://prntscr.com/nqyirl

EDIT: I've had a break through, anything over 7 characters breaks it.

Answer (score 1):

you probably just don't remove the last symbol. my guess is that changing 
 for

```
(int i = startIndex; i < endIndex; i++)
```

to
for

```
(int i = startIndex; i <= endIndex; i++)
```

should fix the problem

Comment: For whatever reason, I tried this last night and it broke it. I can provide details here in a minute, but this wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

why changing it into char[]?
a String has internal a char[], but gives you much more and easier replace functions.

for example originalMessage.replaceAll("test1234","testo22345566")
would replace all test1234 occurences with testo22345566

info about that method:https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-replaceall

this makes it possible to add regex filters instead of a one to one replace configuration. (the replaceAll function on string uses regex for its searching of occurences)

for example

```
#configurables, enjoy
replace-words:
  (?i)test[0-9]{4}: testo22345566
```

would in case of the repleaceAll function on string work on all caseinsensitive values followed by 4 numbers

be aware if the swearword replacer can recreate another swearword it could be needed to pass multiple times over this replacer.

edit: modification because of some comments:

you could also just use your config, but still use the originalMessage.replaceAll(wordOfTheConfigList,replacementword)

```java
String newMessage = originalMessage;
String inBetweenChars = "([\s\._]*)";
for (String swearWord : swearWords){
    String searchWord = "(?i)"+inBetweenChars+String.join(inBetweenChars,swearWord) + inBetweenChars;
    String replaceWith = getConfig().getString("replace-words." + swearWord)
    newMessage = newMessage.replaceAll(searchWord,replaceWith))
}
event.setMessage(newMessage);
```

with this answer you can only use normal text in the config, so no [0-9] or other regex features, as this would result in strange [\s0\s-\s9\s] kinda things (wont work) but as you weren't using regex in that config I hope that's not a real problem.

Comment: the case sensitivity is solved by (?i) parameter for regex, for space sensitivity you could try (?x), but I haven't tested that one yet

Comment: right, but I know mine works, I'd prefer to just find the issue.

Comment: then take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16365305/is-it-possible-to-filter-bad-language-words-using-java

Comment: not what I'm trying to do, this runs off a config file man. It has to all  be editable.