# how to exclude ":\" from being considered as emoji

Tags: java, emoji

I have a string which contains   folder path like "C:\Users\Desktop\facebook.png".
I need to also detect emojis if any from the input string and I am using EmojiUtils.emojify method .
However the ":\" is getting replaced with a confused emoji [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYAzA.png]  .How can I prevent this

Using emoji4j version 5

Answer (score 2):

It depends on which library for EmojiUtils. If you use Emoji4j  >= 6.0( https://github.com/kcthota/emoji4j ),
 the documentation explains how to do this:

```
String text = "http://www.github.com and https://www.google.com are awesome :-).";

EmojiManager.addStopWords("http://", "https://");

EmojiUtils.emojify(userText) //returns http://www.github.com and https://www.google.com are awesome .
```

So in the case described in the question, a stop word could be "C:/", though this might need plenty more.

If you use a different library / version, an approach would be to split the text into a list of strings which are paths or other text, emojify only the parts that are other text, and merge that list again. A similar problem has an answer here: [Is it possible to filter bad language words using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16365305/is-it-possible-to-filter-bad-language-words-using-java)

Comment: I believe addStopWords is supported for v6 onwards

Comment: Yes, I think so